# JPA annotation that will include fields from non-entity super class (from JAR!)

Tags: jpa, inheritance, spring-boot

I am working with spring boot, spring JPA and have following problem: I created some class "B" that extends some class "A" from JAR, put `@Entity` and `@Table` annotations on class "B" (I can't do the same on class "A") but when Spring/Hibernate is creating tables, only fields from class "B" are included.

```
// some class from JAR
// not an Entity
class A { 
    String fieldA; 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
class B extends A {
    String fieldB;
}
```

Table that is created in database

```
+--------+                                +--------+--------+
| fieldB |    but I want this to be made  | fieldA | fieldB |
+--------+                                +--------+--------+
```

How to manage that? Is there some JPA annotation that could be put on class B that would solve this?

**EDIT**: If `@AttributeOverride` annotation is the solution, how to mark that overriden field as `Id` when `@Id` annotation can't be put outside the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `@Id` on a getter.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
class B extends A {
    String fieldB;

    @Id
    @Override
    public String getFieldA() {
        return super.getFieldA();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, I tried that but the problem in that case is that I need to implemet setter too, what I would like to skip. Superclass is made without setters because it's using builder to instatiate it.

Comment: That's true.Builder-pattern and JPA are not the best friends. Two other "solutions" are mapping the values and build the setter from B with reflection(I know...).